# Error:(18, 29) java: ';' expected + Error:(18, 39) java: not a statement

Tags: java, compiler-errors

what is the proplem it should ask for number 1 and number2 and operater

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
        int operand1 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter operator: ");
        String operator = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
        int operand2 =  scan.nextInt();
        if (operator == "+") {
            return int.class(operand1 + operand2);
        }
        else if (operator == "-") {
            return int.class(operand1 - operand2);
        }
        else if (operator == "*") {
            return int.class(operand1 * operand2);
        }
        else {
            return "error...";
        }
    }

}
// Error:(18, 29) java: ';' expected
// Error:(18, 39) java: not a statement
```

**errors**
Error:(18, 29) java: ';' expected  + Error:(18, 39) java: not a statement

Comment: Where did you get `int.class(...)` from? It is not valid Java.

Comment: what to do .....

Comment: Get rid of all the `int.class` bits. Compare strings with `.equals` instead of `==`. Don't create multiple scanners. Also see [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo). Also your `void main` function can't return anything. It's void.

Comment: You are using return in a function, which has no return value (`void`).

Comment: Is more useful to mark on code where exactly is the error, instead of tely us `Error:(18, 29)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. `main` is declared as `void` so you shouldn't `return` anything
2. string comparison is done with `equals` in Java, not `==`
3. you probably want to display the result rather than returning it anyways: use `System.out.print` instead of `return`!
4. as mentioned above: I'm not sure what you wanted to do by wrapping the arithmetic operations with `int.class(...)` but it's not doing what you think it's doing.

See corrections below (or run directly [here](https://onlinegdb.com/ryCuQnukw)):

```
import java.util.Scanner;   

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
        int operand1 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter operator: ");
        String operator = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
        int operand2 =  scan.nextInt();
        if (operator.equals("+")) {
            System.out.print(operand1 + operand2);
        } else if (operator.equals("-")) {
            System.out.print(operand1 - operand2);
        } else if (operator.equals("*")) {
            System.out.print(operand1 * operand2);
        } else {
            System.out.print("error: unknown Operation: " + operator);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: but you forgot the package name but great